# Valid US visa on old passport has a different given name while new passport has a corrected given name, will this be an issue?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, passport-renewals

The old passport with a still valid US visa on it has Given Names: XXX YYY and Surname: YYY

Due to this my visa has the same combination i.e. full name reading XXX YYY YYY (surname twice at the end).

On my new passport this was corrected to Given Name: XXX Surname: YYY

Will this cause an issue during travel? The new passport has the old passport number officially recorded in the alterations page.

I would like to clarify that the name change in the new passport was correcting the old mistake (a clerical error). It is **not an official name change** with legal documents to back it.

Answer (score 5):

If this name correction is properly documented, I do not believe this will be a problem. They have your fingerprint and other personal information on record anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The name on my birth certificate is XXX YYY. The name in my first passport/visa I came to the USA on is YYY XXX**A** ZZZ (ZZZ is my fathers last name however it doesn't appear on my birth certificate) which switches my first and middle names and misspells my transposed first name. I used that passport throughout school in the USA but had my social security number as XXX**O** YYY ZZZ. During that time my name on my I-20 was XXX**O** YYY ZZZ which conflicted my visa/passport but never had a problem at immigration/airport when I presented both.

At my permanent residence interview, the officer declared my name ought to be XXX YYY ZZZ and issued my permanent resident card in that name and when I recently naturalized, I've continued with that. I have **never had any court/legal  documents documenting these variations**.

On the [USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/history-and-genealogy/genealogy/genealogy-notebook/immigrant-name-changes) website it says:

> "We know from experience that records of entry of many aliens into the
>   United States contain assumed or incorrect names and other errors."

Additionally USCIS in official [direction to employers](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/acceptable-documents/examining-documents) says:

> If your employee Presents a document from the List of Acceptable
>   Documents in which his or her name **is spelled slightly differently**
>   than the name he or she wrote in Section 1,   Ask your employee the
>   reason for the difference in spelling. If it reasonably appears to be
>   genuine and to relate to the individual, **you may accept the
>   document**.

Clearly this kind of discrepancy happens more than you would think. You should be fine.