# Missing second surname

Tags: tickets, international-travel

Our international flight is in a couple of days and we are extremely worried because we just found out my wife's name when booking does not match her passport exactly. On her passport her last name is hyphenated like AAAA-BBBB but when I booked I only put AAAA. We called our travel agent who contacted United and they are refusing to make any type of correction. I put my wife's full name online for the passport/immigration information. What can we do?

Thank you

Comment: I guess the airline is 'United' (does it have a longer name?) Where are the flights? International?

Comment: Airline is ANA but is operated by United Airlines. We are going from LAX to NRT Japan.

Comment: Did you try to change it with ANA? If that fails, try calling United yourself. A direct call from you may work. And, as you point out, the passenger details are correct (was her passport number included in those?).

Comment: ANA was contingent on if United changed it as well. I did call United and they told me to call travel agent. So I've just been going in a circle :(. I did put her passport number when I edited her passenger details online last night.

Comment: I feel like they are giving me no options at all to fix this human error and we'll be forced to lose what we've spent on this trip we've been looking forward to for about a year.

Comment: Was her name *ever* just AAAA?  Do you have a name-change document (marriage certificate, for example)?

Comment: Her credit cards have just AAAA. She has not changed her name yet.

Comment: Typically the airline allows a change for a fee though. Have you tried your credit card company if you used a credit card to purchase the ticket? My American Express card customer service have helped get me out of some jams like that.

Comment: Yes it was booked through Chase but all they can do is cancel and re-book which will cost an extra $500 :(. We called TSA and they said we should be okay if we have other proof that that is her. Like credit cards without her second surname.

Comment: Honestly, it's likely to be fine. There's no guarantee, but the most likely situation is that there's no problem, especially if she can show the credit cards.

Comment: It might help to know your wife's name's ethnic background. For example, many Spanish-speaking countries have the system of (Given Name) (Father Surname) (Mother Surname), with the father's name being the principal surname; but such names often get mangled with the parents' surnames hyphenated. Tourist and government personnel are familiar with this discrepancy, and I would try to stay calm about it.

Comment: Yes that is correct, she is hispanic and it's father surname - mother surname. I only included her father's surname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show up for your flight with as many picture ID and documents you can come up with. You can even get a notarized letter (free from your bank) to confirm she is the same person. I even have my ancient expired college and grad school ID cards available to call upon if/when the need arises.

I have had wrong name problems on my documents for the last 19+ years (maybe even 43 years if you consider my original birth certificate has a mistake and leaves out my surname completely) and obtained many visas and boarded literally hundreds of flights with those discrepancies. See my case [**here**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89408/valid-us-visa-on-old-passport-has-a-different-given-name-while-new-passport-has/89461#89461). Haven't been denied boarding or refused a visa for that reason, although I have been questioned a few times. In reality name misspellings occur a lot in life even on official documents.

Be nice, polite, and smile but assertive if necessary to the boarding agent and TSA.

Comment: Thank you all. Just came back from our trip with no issues at all.

Comment: Thank you for posting the update with the outcome. I’m in the same situation right now.