# Mismatch in parent's name in Income tax return and Bank statement for Japanese Visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, paperwork

I am an Indian student and am going to Japan for my summer internship this may. My father's name on his Income tax returns and Bank statements mismatches by a letter from his name on my Passport. Will this cause any issue in getting a Japanese Visa ?

Comment: It shouldn't. Such things happen all the time. I have had mismatches in my passport, real name, and birth certificates for decades.

Comment: The company is paying for my accommodation and travels, so I also think it shouldn't cause any trouble. @SheikPaul

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't. Such things happen all the time. I have had [mismatches in my passport, real name, and birth certificates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89408/valid-us-visa-on-old-passport-has-a-different-given-name-while-new-passport-has/89461#89461) for decades. These things are more common than most people think